# Zendesk Chat Widget not showing in cordova based iOS app, correctly showing in Android and Web

Tags: ios, cordova, zendesk

Zendesk Chat Widget not showing in cordova based iOS app, correctly showing in Android and Web.
Even showing in iOS web too. But it doesn't show in Cordova based iOS app.

I simply added script from official docs and added in my React index.html file. It doesn't work for Cordova based iOS app.

Also adding following lines in config.xml. Still getting this issue.

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*.zendesk.com/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*://*.zdassets.com/*" />
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?